# Replicating Postman endpoints with vanilla python requests

Tags: python-requests, docusignapi

After not being able to get the [provided python API](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client) to work (I simply do not know enough about authentication), but being able to use [provided Postman collections](https://docusign.github.io/postman-esign-api-collection/) to work,

I decided to try and replicate these Collection Endpoints in Python.

I got off to a good start with the auth endpoint

Here it is in Postman:
[image]
[image]

and my python code replicating this:

```
base_url = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/'
params = {'api_password':'true'}
headers = {'X-DocuSign-Authentication':json.dumps({"Username":username,"Password":password,"IntegratorKey": clientid}),
'Content-Type':'application/json'}
auth_req = requests.get(base_url+'login_information', params, headers=headers)
```

Auth request yields 200, just like Postman

But then I try another request to /templates/

Here it is in Postman:
[image]

and headers same as Auth request above

I tried many variations of the following:

```
params = {'accountId':'7787022'}
get_templates = requests.get(base_url+'templates', params, headers=headers)
```

No matter what I try, I get a 404 instead of a 200 like with postman.
**Any idea what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: Can you output the get_templates url as raw text to show us what's being generated?

Comment: it would look like `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/templates`

Comment: There's your problem. It should be `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/templates`

Comment: How come it works in Postman though? PS. I will try the endpoint PSPS. the 404 reason is *The URL provided does not resolve to a resource.*

Comment: Actually, this endpoint works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, it looks like you don't have a fully built BaseUrl. The full body of a base URL will include the server, the rest API version and your account number. Aside from the Login Information and other authentication calls, all standard* REST API calls will start with `https://{{server}}.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/`

A call to GET templates would be made to `https://{{server}}.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/templates`.

**Organization API calls are coming soon and will likely use a different URL.*

Answer (score 0):

The following did not fix, but I thought it would fix, and still think it is importnat information:

In Postman auth call under 'Tests' there is the followign code

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("accountId", jsonData.loginAccounts[0].accountId);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("baseUrl", jsonData.loginAccounts[0].baseUrl);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("password", jsonData.apiPassword);
```

even though this is 'Tests' it is useful for and often used to set variables, (some ppl at my old company used to do this).

In my python code, I need to take the response body from auth request:

```
{
    "loginAccounts": [
        {
            "name": "Aiden McHugh",
            "accountId": "7787022",
            "baseUrl": "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/7787022",
            "isDefault": "true",
            "userName": "Aiden McHugh",
            "userId": "e87........6a4eb",
            "email": "aide....il.com",
            "siteDescription": ""
        }
    ],
    "apiPassword": "HheDl......3MQ="
}
```

and use apiPassword variable to reset password in my header

Comment: That's a bit of a red herring. Either the API password from the Login Information call or your plaintext password can be used for authentication.

Comment: Ok, that would explain why it didn't resolve it. Thought I cracked the case

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out the [python code example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant). It includes authentication and many examples.

Comment: I spent a long time on that, I am sure it is more sophisticated, but as I mentioned in previous tickets, it is too black-boxy. Either I am really dumb, or the docs are not sufficiently clear. The methods are called with variables that do not match namewise between the API settings (from DS sandbox) and the api-code, then you have to figure out which auth system is being used, and what is needed for those it (ie. is a secret key needed?) - the docs are all over the place. At the end of the day, I get some error from Oauth (not even cryptography or library called by your API but even lower level